# Converting a list of dictionaries to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dictionaries that I would like to convert to a dataframe. My list of dictionaries looks like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [{item1: 12}, 
{item2: 10},
{item3: 5},
{item4: 1}]
```

I am using the following code to convert to a dataframe:

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

However the dataframe I get back is a diagonal

```
        0     1     2     3
item1   12   NaN   NaN   NaN
item2   NaN   10   NaN   NaN
item3   NaN   NaN   5    NaN
item4   NaN   NaN   NaN   1
```

I am interested in having the dataframe look like this:

```
index    item_num    value
0          item1     12
1          item2     10
2          item3     5
3          item4     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([tuple(k.items())[0] for k in list_of_dicts], columns=["item_num", "value"])
```

If some `dict` contains more than one items, i.e. `[...,{'item1.1':1, 'item1.2':2},...]`.

```
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([t for d in list_of_dicts for t in d.items()], columns=["item_num", "value"])
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks! Can you explain why the original does not work as intended?

Comment: The  first argument to `DataFrame`, i.e. `list_of_dicts`, is a nested iterable. The indexes/keys (0,1,2,...) of the outer iterable are taken as column names. The  indexes/keys (item1,item2,...) of the inner one are taken as the row names.